# Vuetify v-textarea maxlength on devices

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, textarea, maxlength, onpaste

I have vuetify v-textarea in my page and problem with maxlength in it. In web all is good, but on devices when I paste text inside textarea and then typing I pass over maxlength.

```
    <v-textarea
        id="typo-error-message"
        v-model.trim="$v.message.$model"
        :maxlength="1000"
        :counter="1000"
        :error-messages="$v.message.$error ? desriptionValidationErrorMsg : ''"
        rows="1"
        auto-grow
        outlined
        single-line
    />
```

I was trying to find something on the Internet and came across this codepen. However, it also does not work on devices and exceeds the maxlength.

https://codepen.io/katerlouis/pen/YzPNYoW

Comment: I think it's not related to Vuetify. Maxlength is the native HTML attribute, so you can search from that point of view (type="number" issue is related to native HTML as well).